# PubSubClient - MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE How is it calculated

Tags: mqtt

I'm using an ESP32, and I want to rule out a probable MQTT error. In `PubSubClient` , `MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE` is set to 256. Is 256 the size for message only ? if not, what is left for message only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the maximum size of an entire packet.  In `publish()` this check is done:

```
if (MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE < MQTT_MAX_HEADER_SIZE + 2+strlen(topic) + plength) {
```

So the maximum length of a message payload will be

```
MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE - MQTT_MAX_HEADER_SIZE - 2 - strlen(topic)
```

`MQTT_MAX_HEADER_SIZE` is defined as 5, so if you have, for example, a 20 character topic you would have `256 - 5 - 2 - 20 = 229` bytes left for your payload.